# Error using categorical data in Pipeline with OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, one-hot-encoding

I would like to build a pipeline to predict 'Survival' from the three features 'SibSp_category', 'Parch_category', 'Embarked'.

In the preprocessing step, I use (1) OrdinalEncoder to convert the strings to integers, that shall be (2) imputed by SimpleImputer using the most frequent value. (3) from the imputed features, I would like to create dummy-variables using OneHotEncoder which shall be used as the features in xgb. However, when running the optimizer, I receive a ValueError and I suspect it's thrown by the OneHotEncoder.

Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import xgboost as xgb
import lightgbm as lgb
from skopt import BayesSearchCV

df = pd.DataFrame({'SibSp_category': ['alone', 'couple', 'group', 'alone', 'couple', 'group',np.nan],
    'Parch_category': ['alone', 'small', 'large', np.nan, 'alone', 'small', 'large'],
    'Embarked': [np.nan, 'S', 'C', 'Q', 'C', 'Q', 'S'],
    'Survived': [0,1,1,0,0,1,0]})

X = df.drop("Survived", axis=1)
y = df["Survived"]
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

preprocessors = make_column_transformer(
    (OrdinalEncoder(), ['SibSp_category', 'Parch_category', 'Embarked']),
    (SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'), ['SibSp_category', 'Parch_category', 'Embarked']),
    (OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', drop='first'), ['SibSp_category', 'Parch_category', 'Embarked'])
)

pipelines = {
    'xgb': {
        'model': Pipeline([('preprocessor', preprocessors),
                           ('classifier', xgb.XGBClassifier())]),
        'params': {
            'classifier__learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1],
            'classifier__max_depth': [3, 5, 7, 9],
            'classifier__n_estimators': [100, 200]
        }
}
}

optimizer = BayesSearchCV(pipeline['model'], pipeline['params'], n_jobs=-1, cv=2, 
                              scoring='accuracy', n_iter=20)
optimizer.fit(X_train, y_train)

...
--> 390                 raise self._exception
    391             finally:
    392                 # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'alone'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not what `ColumnTransformer()` does. It runs those three functions on the columns supplied and concatenates the results.

If you wish to run imputation and encoding in order, `SimpleImputer()` and `OneHotEncoder()` should be separate pipeline steps, wrapped into `ColumnTranformer()` if needed, e.g.:

```
preprocessors = make_column_transformer(
    (Pipeline(
        [
            ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
            ('encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', drop='first')),
        ]
        ), ['SibSp_category', 'Parch_category', 'Embarked'])
)
```

For the latest sklearn releases, pre-encoding with `OrdinalEncoder()` is excessive as the other functions support categorical values.